# Subquery is slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table with about 10 Million rows. 
For each row, I have an `id` column and `date` column. The `id` column is not unique, and for one `id` there are multiple rows with different values for `date`, typically 3-6 dates for each `id`. I want to select the rows with the latest `date` for their `id`.

My query:

```
SELECT   id,
         date
FROM     tab a
WHERE    a.date = (SELECT MAX(date)
                   FROM   tab b
                   WHERE  a.id=b.id)
```

is very slow and takes minutes to complete. It feels this could be done much faster. What are the best practices here?

Comment: Try a JOIN instead, i.e. move subquery from WHERE to FROM.

Comment: In addition to the above comment, the subquery should involve a `GROUP BY id` statement.

Comment: try indexing the table

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: Using mysql. Already have an index for the `id' column. Would an index for the `date' column' help much? Would someone write the optimized query to be more specific?

Comment: *Which version* of MySQL. MySQL 8 has windowing functions (ROW_NUMBER(), RANK()) that make this type of query much easier and better performing.

Comment: 5.7.26 (weird, because it's a fresh install from last month)

Comment: Are your columns indexed? Also, DanB's answer seems the easiest and fastest way to go. Also, a "divide and conquer" approach can help; instead of a single big query, can you get chunks of data and then integrate them?

Comment: Yes: you need to add an index to the `date` column.

Comment: adding an index on (id, date) helped a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just ?

```
SELECT   id,
         MAX(date) date
FROM     tab
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: Will work perfect (as long no additional columns are selected.)

Comment: This reduces time to 4 minutes from over 10 minutes before, but isn't there a way to do it much faster? My motivating idea is that if I had an array of (id, date) in a standard programming language, I would be able to perform this task in one pass though the array (using a hash table)

Comment: adding an index on (id, date) improves to 1 minute

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that there are more columns you want to get from the table (otherwise, DanB's solution is the best way to go).

Let's split this in two steps:

1. Get the max dates for each `id`
2. Get the required data

Step one is easy:

```
SELECT id, max(date)
FROM tab
GROUP BY id
```

**Important:** both columns must be indexed.

Now, step two is the hard part. How to get all the data you need?

What I'd do is:

- Create a temp table with the result of the query above,
- Index it, and
- Join the table with this new temp table.

So, let's try:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_dates
     SELECT id, max(date) as mdate
     FROM tab
     GROUP BY id;

ALTER TABLE temp_dates
     ADD UNIQUE INDEX u_id (id),
     ADD INDEX i_mdate (mdate);

SELECT a.id, a.date -- Add all the columns you need
FROM tab AS a
     INNER JOIN temp_dates AS b ON a.id=b.id and a.date=b.mdate;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @oysteing I agree with the creation of the table, but I'm not sure about the automatic indexing... In practice, it was always faster (some times dramatically) when I created the temp table and then used it in the join than using a subquery.... But it might have been just my impression

Comment: (Deleted the first comment since it was sent before it was completed)

MySQL will create the temporary table and the index automatically if you write the query as: 

SELECT a.id, a.date FROM tab AS a INNER JOIN (SELECT id, max(date) FROM tab GROUP BY id) AS b ON a.id = b. id AND a.date = b.date;

A combined index on tab(id, date) is still needed.

Comment: That changed with MySQL 5.6.  Since then, indexes on the derived table is created automatically if it can help the join.  In this case, the indexes will probably not be used since the temporary table will be smaller than the original table.  Hence, the best plan will be to scan the temporary table and do index-lookups into the original table.

Answer (score 0):

First of all:
**id**'s should be unique. That's their purpose.

Now my recommendation:

```
select
  id,
  max(date) as latest_date
from a

join b
  on b.id = a.id

group by a.id

order by latest_date;
```

Comment: In my case id's are not unique (I am simplifying my use case for the sake of the question). In any case, your select does not improve over the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your query might be the fastest way to approach this.  But you definitely need an index on `tab(id, date)` for performance.  Both columns in the index.

If you have another table of ids, then the following is often the fastest approach:

```
select ids.id,
       (select max(t.date)
        from tab t
        where t.id = ids.id
       ) as max_date;
```

This requires the same index but does not require scanning the full table (as well as the index).